# How to connect to a remote SQL Server using servername, username & password

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to connect to a remote SQL Server using servername, username & password in SQL Server 2005 ?

Comment: this has a simple answer that you could easily find yourself....

Comment: also, you have asked 75 questions and only upvoted 3 times? How come?

Comment: if you can't find this yourself you shouldn't be allowed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're talking exactly about what your question asks, how to connect to a remote MSSQL instance *inside* SQL Server, rather than through SQL Server Management Studio because 1) you don't mention SSMS and 2) it's pretty obvious how to connect with SSMS (I mean, the connect box is *right there* when you start it).

To connect to one MSSQL instance from another you can use [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx). You can query data from linked servers, and if they are configured for RPC Out you can also execute SQL against them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the server is configured for integrated security, there is no way of doing it without changing the security option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) website - it shows you how to build a **connection string** that will allow you to connect from your machine to a remote SQL Server instance.

That connection string will typically look something like:

```
server=YourServerHere;database=YourDatabase;User ID=YourUser;Password=Top$ecret
```

But there are lots of options and additional things you can specify - the ConnectionStrings.com web site shows and explains them all!